# UISwipeGestureRecogniser in UICollectionViewCell issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a `UICollectionView` where each cell has a left and right `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` which gives the illusion of flipping an image for a menu. The thing that I cannot figure out how to do is "closing/flipping" previously flipped cell before flipping another cell.

Here's screenshot of what it looks like now:

[image]

```
class Note: UICollectionViewCell {
var isFlipped = false

func addSwipeGestures() {
    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeLeft(swipe:)))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left
    contentView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeRight(swipe:)))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right
    contentView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
}

@objc func swipeLeft(swipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if isFlipped {
        flipToBackView(options: .transitionFlipFromLeft)
    }
    else {
        flipToFrontView(options: .transitionFlipFromLeft)
    }
}

@objc func swipeRight(swipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if isFlipped {
        flipToBackView(options: .transitionFlipFromRight)
    }
    else {
        flipToFrontView(options: .transitionFlipFromRight)
    }
}

func flipToBackView(options: UIView.AnimationOptions ) {
    UIView.transition(with: backView, duration: 0.3, options: options, animations: { [unowned self] in
        self.coverImageView.isHidden = false
        self.titleLabel.isHidden = false
        self.titleView.isHidden = false
        self.isFlipped = !self.isFlipped
    })
}

func flipToFrontView(options: UIView.AnimationOptions) {
    UIView.transition(with: backView, duration: 0.3, options: options, animations: { [unowned self] in
        self.coverImageView.isHidden = true
        self.titleLabel.isHidden = true
        self.titleView.isHidden = true
        self.isFlipped = !self.isFlipped
    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [delegation pattern](https://www.appcoda.com/swift-delegate/) for this. E.g. you could add a protocol to the Note class:

```
protocol FlipDelegate: class {
    func willFlip(note: Note)
}
```

Make the ViewController conform to this protocol, store the reference to the last flipped card and flip the last flipped card again:

```
    weak var lastFlippedNote: Note?

    func willFlip(_ note: Note) {
        lastFlippedNote?. flipToBackView(options: .transitionFlipFromLeft)
        lastFlippedNote = note

    }
```

Add a weak reference to the Note class like `weak var flipDelegate: FlipDelegate?` and assign the viewController to the cell in the `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`.
In your swipe actions you can call `willFlip(_:)` e.g. when you flip to the front side of your note like:

```
@objc func swipeLeft(swipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if isFlipped {
        flipToBackView(options: .transitionFlipFromLeft)
    }
    else {
        flipToFrontView(options: .transitionFlipFromLeft)
        flipDelegate?.willFlip(note: self)
    }
}

@objc func swipeRight(swipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if isFlipped {
        flipToBackView(options: .transitionFlipFromRight)
    }
    else {
        flipToFrontView(options: .transitionFlipFromRight)
        flipDelegate?.willFlip(note: self)
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: The only thing that I dont understand is where is this line of code coming from `lastFlippedNote?.flipToBackView(options: .transitionFlipFromLeft)` ? `lastFlippedNote` is of type `Note` whereas `flipTobackView` is a method in cell itself. I cannot call `flipToBackView` on the `lastFlippedNote` instance

Comment: The view controller which displays the cells needs to conform to the `FlipDelegate` (e.g. `class CollectionViewController: FlipDelegate`) and the view controller needs a property `weak var lastFlippedNote: Note?`. Since `flipToFrontView(options:)` is a method in the `Note` class you should be able to call it.

Comment: I misunderstood you the first time. That made more sense. The problem is that I can still flip all cells and then when i try to flip them back ONLY then it triggers the `willFlip()` method.

Comment: @BoldLion okay in this case you have to move the call `willFlip(note:)` to the if body instead of the else body.